# Is this proof correct or am I trying to prove a falsehood?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Suppose that we have three possible outcomes $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ (if that helps, suppose they are monetary amounts) and some threshold $x$. Then, we also know that
\begin{gather*}
x\geqslant\alpha\\
x\geqslant\tau\beta+(1-\tau)\gamma
\end{gather*}
for any $\tau\in[0,1]$. My **goal** is to show that if the above Inequalities hold, then
\begin{gather*}
x\geqslant(1-\rho-\pi)\alpha+\rho\beta+\pi\gamma
\end{gather*}
for any $(\rho,\pi)\in[0,1]^2$ such that $\rho+\tau\in[0,1]$. My attempt is as follows. Let's go step by step.

1. Given the premises, define some $\varphi\in[0,1]$ and then write
   \begin{gather*}
   x\geqslant\varphi\alpha+(1-\varphi)\left[\tau\beta+(1-\tau)\gamma\right]
   \end{gather*}
2. Then, resolve some multiplications to get
   \begin{gather*}
   x\geqslant\varphi\alpha+(\tau-\varphi\tau)\beta+(1-\varphi\tau-\varphi-\tau)\gamma
   \end{gather*}
3. Because $\tau\in[0,1]$ and $\varphi\in[0,1]$, it follows that
   \begin{gather*}
   0\leqslant\tau-\varphi\tau\leqslant1\\
   0\leqslant1-\varphi\tau-\varphi-\tau\leqslant1
   \end{gather*}
4. Therefore, let $\rho=\tau-\varphi\tau$ and $\pi=1-\varphi\tau-\varphi-\tau$ and then write:
   \begin{gather*}
   x\geqslant\varphi\alpha+\rho\beta+\tau\gamma
   \end{gather*}
5. Then, notice that
   \begin{align*}
   1-\rho-\pi&=1-\tau+\varphi\tau-1-\varphi\tau+\varphi+\tau\\
   &=1+\varphi-1\\
   &=\varphi
   \end{align*}
6. And *voilà*! It seems we're done, because
   \begin{gather*}
   x\geqslant(1-\rho-\pi)\alpha+\rho\beta+\pi\gamma
   \end{gather*}

Therefore, my question is: **is this simple proof correct?** If it is false, please state why; if it is true ***only under some unstated conditions***, please state them. If it is correct... Well, then just say it.

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time and effort.

Comment: I think this is easier than you are making it out to be. The two inequalities imply that $x \ge \max(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ which gives the result immediately I think.

Comment: @guy True. I hadn't seen it this way. Would you be so kind to transform your comment into an answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging in $\tau = 1$ we get $x \ge \beta$, while plugging in $\tau = 0$ we get $x \ge \gamma$. Let $\delta = \max\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$; then we have $x \ge \delta$. So, we have:
\begin{align*}
(1-\rho-\pi)\alpha + \rho\beta + \pi\gamma
&\le (1 - \rho - \pi) \delta + \rho \delta + \pi \delta\\
&\le\delta\\
&\le x. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for confirming the result and providing a significant shortcut to get to it.